# Powershell: batch rename and keep extension?

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

Is it possible to batch rename a series of files and keep the original extensions in a sequence?

For example, if you had the files in a directory:

```
dogfile1.jpg, wolffile493.png, and dogfile59.jpg
```

and wanted to rename them `dog1.jpg, dog2.png, dog3.jpg`

I saw you can use this to batch rename but it renames it to the extension you select (ex. jpg):

```
$nr=1 
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘NewFile{0}.jpg’ -f $nr++)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
PS C:\tmp\y> $nr=1; Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘NewFile{0}{1}’ -f $nr++, $_.extension)}
```

Here's a quick demonstration:

```
PS C:\tmp\y> echo "123" > firstfile.txt
PS C:\tmp\y> echo "abc" > secondfile.jpg
PS C:\tmp\y> dir -Name
firstfile.txt
secondfile.jpg
PS C:\tmp\y> $nr=1; Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘NewFile{0}{1}’ -f $nr++, $_.extension)}
PS C:\tmp\y> dir -Name
NewFile1.txt
NewFile2.jpg
PS C:\tmp\y> type *
123
abc
PS C:\tmp\y>
```